# key Iterator for chaining hash table java

Tags: java, iterator, key, hashtable

I am building an inner class of key and value iterator for my chained hash table. I am having trouble with it. I first checked one HashTable entry, and then iterating the linked list it points at. As far as my tracking of this key iterator, the logic should be right. Here is what it looks like:

```
private class KeyIterator implements Iterator<K> {

    private int currentIndex; // Current position in hash table
    //private int numberLeft; // Number of entries left in iteration

    private KeyIterator() {
        currentIndex = 0;
        //numberLeft = numberOfEntries;
    } // end default constructor

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return currentIndex < numberOfEntries;
    } // end hasNext

    public K next() {
        K result = null;

        if (hasNext()) {
            LList<TableEntry> items = hashTable[currentIndex];
            if (items != null) {
                Iterator<TableEntry> traverse = items.getIterator();
                while (traverse.hasNext()) {
                    TableEntry<K, V> item = traverse.next();
                    result = item.key;

//                        if (items.contains(item)) {
//                            hashTable[currentIndex] = items;
//                        }
//                        numberLeft--;
                    numberOfEntries++;
                }//reaches last entry in hash table w/ current index
                currentIndex++;
            } else {//items == null, that is, there is no llist in the current hash table
                currentIndex++;
            }
        } else {//reaches the end of the hash table
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
     }
        return result;
    } // end next

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    } // end remove

} // end KeyIterator
```

However, in the test program I wrote,

```
import java.util.Iterator;
public class Demos {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashDict dictionary = new HashDict();

    dictionary.add("hello", 13);
    System.out.println("after first add: " + dictionary.toString());
    dictionary.displayTable();

    System.out.println("after second add: " + dictionary.add("hi", 12));
    dictionary.displayTable();

 }
}
```

I got results like this

```
after first add: 13
null, null
after second add: 12
null, null
null, null
```

The displayTable is just a method in the HashTable class that used to test iterater methods. It looks like this:

```
public void displayTable() {
    Iterator traverse = getKeyIterator();
    Iterator traverseValues = getValueIterator();

    while (traverse.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(traverse.next());
        System.out.print(", " + traverseValues.next());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Why this keyIterator method work like this? Any help would be really appreciated!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Update version of Key Iterator:

```
private class KeyIterator implements Iterator<K> {

    private int currentIndex; // Current position in hash table
    private int numberLeft; // Number of entries left in iteration

    private KeyIterator() {
        currentIndex = 0;
        numberLeft = numberOfEntries;
    } // end default constructor

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return numberLeft > 0;
    } // end hasNext

    public K next() {
        K result = null;
        if (hasNext()) {
            LList<TableEntry> items = hashTable[currentIndex];
            Iterator<TableEntry> traverse = items.getIterator();

            while (traverse.hasNext()) {
                TableEntry<K, V> item = new TableEntry();
                item = traverse.next();
                result = item.key;

                numberLeft--;
            }
            currentIndex++;
        } else {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return result;
    } // end next

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    } // end remove
} // end KeyIterator
```

Now my error is like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at HashDict$KeyIterator.next(HashDict.java:48)
at Demos.main(Demos.java:40)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it makes no sense for your key iterator to increment `numberOfEntries`. Since that variable is not an instance variable of the `KeyIterator` class, I'm assuming it's an instance variable of the enclosing class. It should only be modified when you add or remove element to the hash table.

Another issue is that `currentIndex` is not enough to track the position of the current key. You need the index of the current entry in the `hashTable` + the current link in the linked list of the current entry. This will allow you to iterate to the next link in that linked list in constant time.

Comment: That makes sense. I misused numberOfEntries as the index of current link in the linked list. I add another counter to track the link and made some changes to the next() method, but I still got an error. I will update the new method and the error in my question. Thx so much!